# how to freeze a column in a table in power bi

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I need to freeze the first column of my table in power bi so that when scrolling it stays fixed. How it happens in excel
**for example (screenshot)**
[image]

I've looked through all the options in the preview pane and haven't found any solutions

Answer (score 1):

there is no way to freeze column/row in Powerbi.

as below attached, you can adjust columns width to make all columns shown.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Freeze pane style settings as in Excel are not available in Power BI.

Answer (score 0):

You might try the Matrix visual. Drill down to the latest level of hierarchy, then go to Format and uncheck the Stepped layout option under Row headers.

Answer (score 0):

I am struggling with this, too.

Using [Table] visual does not have freeze feature (disappointing). I have 30+ columns and scrolling is inevitable.

Using [Matrix] visual does freeze the rows given "Stepped layout" is off but if you have multiple expanded row headers, alternating colors does not apply to them (except the last one). And Matrix actually does not work very well for multiple dimensions working towards single entity (disappointing)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with big tables and a lot of scrolling. I deal with inconvenience with help of parameters.

To solve this, I group the columns and filter them with slicer.

Comment: It would be great to add a quick description of how to achieve the grouping and filtering steps.